# Parsing milliseconds from a unix date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, unix-timestamp

Converting a `DateTime` to unix convention using `%s%L` (`%s` means seconds since Jan 1st 1970, `%L` means to append 3 digits to represent milliseconds) give this:

```rb
DateTime.now.strftime '%s%L'
=> "1656279075654"
```

How can I get a `DateTime` back from this?

`DateTime.strptime('1656279075654', '%s%L')` gives an error, as `strptime` doesn't seem to know `%L` strangely.

Comment: `DateTime` is for historic dates. You probably want `Time` which you could get via `Time.at('1656279075654'.to_i.quo(1000))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
secs = '1656279075654'.to_f / 1000

DateTime.strptime(secs.to_s, '%s')
```

or

```
DateTime.strptime('1656279075654', '%Q')
```

(`%Q` - number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)